# Sequelize associations: Can't add associations, throws TypeError

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am a newbie to `postgres` and `Sequelize`. I come from NoSQL background, so this is a bit daunting to me.

First of all this is my project directory:

```
server/
    components/
        center/
            center.model.js
            center.controller.js
            center.routes.js
```

So, I am following a modules based architecture.

Here's my `center.models.js`:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../../config/sequelize');

const Inventory = require('../inventory/inventory.model');

const Center = sequelize.define('center', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
        },
    },
    zone: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
        },
    },
    lat: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    },
    long: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    },
    nearest_metro: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    metro_distance: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    },
    address: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    google_map: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    landmark: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    landmark_directions: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    active: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true,
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    }
});

Center.hasMany(Inventory);

module.exports = Center;
```

And this is my `SpacePartner` model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../../config/sequelize.js');

const Center = require('../center/center.model.js');

const SpacePartner = sequelize.define('space_partner', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
        },
    },
    active: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true,
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    }
});

SpacePartner.hasMany(Center);

module.exports = SpacePartner;
```

And this is how I am using the two models in my `space_partner.controller.js`:

```
    const CreateSpacePartner = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {
            spacePartner,
            center,
            inventory,
        } = req.body;

        const [createdSP, createdCenter, createdInventory] = await Promise.all([SpacePartner.create(spacePartner), Center.create(center), Inventory.create(inventory)]);

        createdCenter.addSpacePartner(createdSP);

        createdInventory.addCenter(createdCenter);

        createdInventory.addInventoryType(inventory.inventory_type_id);

        const [updatedCenter, updatedInventory] = await Promise.all([createdCenter.save({
            fields: ['space_partner_id']
        }), createdInventory.save({
            fields: ['center_id', 'inventory_type_id']
        })]);

        return res.status(200).json({
            spacePartner: createdSP,
            center: updatedCenter,
            inventory: updatedInventory,
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Sorry, we are facing some issue right now. Please, try again later.',
        });
    }
};
```

Now, the issue is that I am getting `TypeError` on `addSpacePartner` `addCenter` and `addInventoryType`.

I was following the official docs.

I did go through other tutorials, but they had more of MVC architecture, I don't want to go back to restructuring my code.

Any help would this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work `createdCenter.addSpacePartner(createdSP);`, to work, we need to define the relationship between `Center` and `SpacePartner`.  So it should be

`Center.hasMany(SpacePartners)`

Once you have this, these functions should be available to you.

You can read more about association [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)

The code for `Inventory` is not posted, so its hard to say about that.